# Telling typescript to to not add ["default'] to new class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, modbus

TypeScript code

```
import ModbusRTU from 'modbus-serial';
var modbus = new ModbusRTU();
modbus.connectTCP("192.168.1.5", { port: 502 });
modbus.setID(1);

setInterval(function() {
    modbus.writeRegister(2048, 2);
}, 100);
```

transpiles to

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var modbus_serial_1 = require("modbus-serial");
var modbus = new modbus_serial_1["default"](); //  <-- HERE
modbus.connectTCP("192.168.1.5", { port: 502 });
modbus.setID(1);
setInterval(function () {
    modbus.writeRegister(2048, 2);
}, 100);
```

However, the code only works without the `["default"]` in class instantiation - like so

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var modbus_serial_1 = require("modbus-serial");
var modbus = new modbus_serial_1(); //  <-- HERE
modbus.connectTCP("192.168.1.5", { port: 502 });
modbus.setID(1);
setInterval(function () {
    modbus.writeRegister(2048, 2);
}, 500);
```

How to tell the transpiler to nod add it to the code?

Comment: Your import uses the default import syntax. try `import { ModbusRTU } from 'modbus-serial';`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thank you, unfortunately transpiling produces `Module '"./node_modules/modbus-serial"' has no exported member 'ModbusRTU'.`

Comment: then `import ModbusRTU = require('modbus-serial');`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I have tried that as well, this produces `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.`

Comment: I have found out that it tranpiles and works despite the complaints about the `new`, but how to get rid of an error?

Comment: @delmadord You could try asserting `var modbus = new ModbusRTU() as any;`

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is running into this problem. It seems like the exports of this library are a bit faulty. I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/yaacov/node-modbus-serial/issues/323) and a pull request to fix it [here](https://github.com/yaacov/node-modbus-serial/pull/324).

**Edit: My patch was applied to this library, hence this issue should not arise in the future :)**